# Kubuntu takes a long time to boot

Tags: boot, swap, kubuntu

Checked on many places, and no solution satisfied me, so giving out the info I believe that should help to know the issue. Thanks in advanced:

`$systemd-analyze`
Startup finished in 4.424s (firmware) + 12.586s (loader) + 5.492s (kernel) + 1min 48.756s (userspace) = 2min 11.260s graphical.target reached after 1min 48.715s in userspace

`blkid`
/dev/sda4: UUID="ae29f117-c886-49b1-93ef-d2a77666ef62" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3bfaca8c-c4ea-4232-bd3f-00cfbc837627"

`cat /etc/fstab`

/ was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=ae29f117-c886-49b1-93ef-d2a77666ef62 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

/boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=58FA-8640  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1

swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=d65012d0-ebd9-4bf9-ae69-9e2ec6978b5a none            swap    sw              0       0

## EDIT

A couple of more information pieces:

`$systemd-analyze blame` only the services with more than a second time

```
17.535s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.743s gpu-manager.service
 4.658s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 1.744s dev-sda4.device
```

`$systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @1min 48.618s
└─multi-user.target @1min 48.618s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 31.079s +17.535s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 30.975s +44ms
      └─network.target @1min 30.921s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.564s +350ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.560s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.550s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.550s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.549s +790us
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.541s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @2.137s +511ms
                      └─apparmor.service @1.670s +416ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.622s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration.mnt.mount @1min 42.792s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 42.333s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @624ms
                                └─keyboard-setup.service @457ms +166ms
                                  └─systemd-journald.socket @448ms
                                    └─system.slice @444ms
                                      └─-.slice @444ms
```

Comment: `1min 48.756s (userspace)` –  Look at `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` to see what's taking so long.  Then use `sudo apt purge ...` and `sudo systemctl disable ...` to remove and disable services you don't need or care about.  If it's a spinning platter HDD, there's a limit to how much you can speed it up, but 2min is pretty excessive.

Comment: @xiota if it was an hdd, I would understand it, but not a lot. However, it is a ssd, dual boot, though

Comment: Please `sudo systemd-analyze plot > /tmp/bootup.svg` and upload it somewhere. Also you could scroll through `journalctl -b` output and try finding stuff which takes a lot of time.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I don't know what is this, but https://github.com/chelmi00/shared_files/blob/6b14c9f27c6847e1c038b5e134bad0a2eb19f1a4/bootup.svg

Comment: Your system seemingly boots in around 7 seconds and then starts waiting for something, only I've no idea what. What does happen if you boot with `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`? If it boots in ~7 seconds, you might have issues with KDM/SDDM.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I found it. I'm going to answer it. Thanks a lot for that understanding of systemd-analyze plot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked while booting, pressed F10, and there appeared "A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/d65012d0... (53s / 1min 30s)"

This meant that it is searching for a disk with the uuid starting with d65012d0, but it isn't there.

## Solution

Your uuid will most likely be different. However, I'm giving you my solution, you can apply it by changing the uuid.

Output `cat /etc/fstab` and check which file system is the one with the uuid d65012d0... Afterwards, check on gparted or disks and find the partition that corresponds with the file system, in my case it was swap. Copy the uuid corresponding with the partition, and paste it instead of the one in `/etc/fstab`

If a graphical explanation is needed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h23oQr8Nvqc

Comment: Unfortunately, as it stands, your answer will not help other users since you specify a UUID of a file system. The properties of UUIDs include that they are *Unique* -- which means no one else, all across the world, will have the UUID you are seeing. I suggest specifying the file system more generally, and rephrase the answer to be more generic.